# Unable to Sort List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am an absolute novice in Flutter. I am trying to display a list of girls based on their distance from me. For this purpose, I created a class called Girls with properties of name and distance.

**Code**:

```
class Girls {
  String name;
  int distance;

  Girls(this.name, this.distance);
}
```

In a stateful widget: GirlsScreen, I am trying to display the list of girls in a ListTile.

**Code**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/model/girls.dart';

class GirlsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GirlsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GirlsScreen> createState() => _GirlsScreenState();
}

class _GirlsScreenState extends State<GirlsScreen> {
  int distance = 15;

List<Girls> allGirls = [
    Girls("Reshmita", 25),
    Girls("Ankita", 17),
    Girls("Rupali", 42),
    Girls("Monica", 50),
    Girls("Sakshi", 9)
  ];

allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Slider(
            min: 1.0,
            max: 100.0,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set distance value',
            value: distance.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeDistance(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Current distance is $distance kms"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: allGirls.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.girl_outlined),
                  trailing: Text("${allGirls[index].distance} km away"),
                  title: Text("${allGirls[index].name}"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**The following line is giving an error**:

```
allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
```

**Error message shown in the image below**:

[image]

How do I sort my list so as to display the girls from nearest to farthest. This is how my app looks:

[image]

Comment: I think you have a typo, try this `allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance)));`

Comment: allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance)); this line must be inside `initState` method

Comment: @esentis your code as an extra ) at the end.

Comment: @Nagual Thanks a lot, code works perfectly after including the line inside the initState().